How did I lose 10 rep, when the answer is +3 with no downvotes?
I have an answer on a question titled 'How to connect speakers to a Nad 3020 amp?'
Somehow I got a -10 applied to it, but the answer is sitting at +3, with no downvotes shown.
What logic is applied to the above phenomenon?

The answer in question is https://music.stackexchange.com/a/138435/101570. OP got an unupvote (https://i.sstatic.net/2Ye4bgM6.png) and misunderstood that +3 is the number of upvotes and not rep gained, while the -10 is rep loss from one upvote that was removed, and not from 10 downvotes (or 5 or whatever the exact assumption is)

Thanks to all for your support. I don't frequent meta, and have no real wish to. However, the numbers just didn't add up, but there should have been a reference. I paid the price for that! And Zoe managed to reveal a solution, which wouldn't have been forthcoming from the information given on the M:P&T site - unless it came later. Season's greetings, and thanks all for your efforts, mostly polite!

@Tim thank you for your response. I will share 2 things which should help in future: 1) these sorts of "how did this happen" support questions about a specific post could have been answered on the meta specific to that site, in this case the M:P&T Meta site. SE meta (ie this site) is more for network-wide issues. 2) We want to help you, but in order to give you the best help, we need as much relevant information as possible. The downvotes here are 100% coming from your original question being low quality/lacking details. Help us help you next time :)

As Zoe correctly found out, it does make sense, and I will try to explain what happened.
As can be seen in the OP's reputation tab:

Yesterday four users upvoted, giving net score of 4, and 40 reputation:

Today, one of the four users who upvoted, decided to undo the upvote (not reverse, just undo) and this resulted in the loss of 10 reputation that you noticed:


The answer still has the three other upvotes (i.e. score of 3), you still have net gain of 30 reputation, and no loss of reputation as result of the answer. Now it's as if the user who undid the vote has just never voted on it.

It did not show as an 'unupvote'. Had it done so, the question would not have needed to be posed.

@Tim well, you never explained where exactly you saw the problem, you wrote this in a very unclear way and hence all the downvotes you got. So, where exactly did you see the "score shows 10" etc? Adding screenshots also helps a lot.

And that’s why you should vote to close unclear questions instead of guessing what the asker meant.

@user3840170 I did, but then Zoe figured this out, so I retracted the close vote and posted the comment as answer, after giving some more details. This is not a guess, that's is exactly what happened, and OP just didn't know about  the "unupvote" option.

…and instead of taking others’ guesses at face value.

@user3840170 if that was really just a guess, I'd just upvote the comment and not post answer. But I just happen to be convinced that's the actual explanation. It's fine to disagree, but I stand behind my answer.
